# Ubuntu 19.04 icon resize

Tags: icons, desktop-environments, 19.04, do-release-upgrade

I have Just upgraded my ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 via `do-release-upgrade`.
In ubuntu 18.10 i could right click on each desktop icon separately and resize the icon of that file.(Using GNOME)
But this is removed now and i cannot resize each icon "separately".
I want to know how can i have it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now indeed, things work differently. This is because there is a technical change in how desktop icons are handled.

Prior to Ubuntu 18.10, desktop icons were handled by the file manager Files, a.k.a. nautilus. However, the developers of the Gnome Desktop dropped support for desktop icons in nautilus several versions ago. This is why Ubuntu shipped with an older version of nautilus.

Currently, Ubuntu again ships with the most recent version of nautilus. Now, desktop icons are supported through a Gnome Shell extension. This is a quite recent extension. It still has some limitations, including where you cannot resize individual icons on your desktop anymore.

Comment: Is there any way to have it back?